# cakephp call action through button

Tags: cakephp, view, controller, action

i wish to call a controller's action through form->button.
I have following things in the web page:

- a search form
- a table with delte option as postLink
- 2 buttons that should call the same action onclick.
  My problem is that when i click on any of the buttons, the post request isn't fired. Below is my code:
  view.ctp

  echo $this->Form->create('Search', array(
          'type' => 'file',
          'url' => array(
              'controller' => 'artists',
              'action' => 'index',
          ),
      ));
  echo $this->Form->input('name');
  echo $this->Form->end(array(
      'label' => 'Search Artist',
      'class' => 'btn btn-info controls'
      ));

  echo $this->For....

  ```
  echo '' . $this->Form->postlink('',
                      array('action' => 'delete',
                          $row['Artist']['id']),
                      array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
                  );
  ```

  echo $this->Form->button('Featured', array(
                      'name' => 'submit',
                      'value' => 'Featured',
                      'type' => 'submit',
                      'url' => array(
                  'controller' => 'artists',
                  'action' => 'index',
              ),
                  ));

  echo $this->Form->button('Unfeatured', array(
                  'name' => 'submit',
                  'value' => 'Unfeatured',
                  'type' => 'submit',
                  'url' => array(
              'controller' => 'artists',
              'action' => 'index',
          ),
              ));

controller:

```
public function isFeatured() {
    if ($this->params->data['submit'] == 'Featured') {
        //code
    } else if($this->params->data['submit'] == 'Unfeatured') {
        //code
    }
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

where am i getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your form declaration doesn't point the action to your 'isFeatured' function in your controller. You should rewrite your buttons to be actual forms. Buttons themselves don't submit.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Search', array('action'=>'isFeatured'));
echo $this->Form->hidden('featured', array('value'=>'1'));
echo $this->Form->end('Featured');

echo $this->Form->create('Search', array('action'=>'isFeatured'));
echo $this->Form->hidden('featured', array('value'=>'0'));
echo $this->Form->end('Not Featured');
```

Controller:

```
public function isFeatured() {
   if($this->request->data){
      if($this->request->data['Search']['featured'] == '1'){
         //..Set the artist as featured
      }
      if($this->request->data['Search']['featured'] == '0'){
         //..Set the artist as not featured
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: but then how will the controller get the request data. I mean I have 2 forms on a page- a search form and a form below with 2 buttons-featured and not featured. I cant create separate forms for featured and not featured.

Comment: in your 2 seperate forms like I have above. The value is 1 in the featured and 0 in the not featured. So In the controller you evaluate the submitted data and perform save based on the evaluation. Or, like you say, you can create 2 seperate forms, views, and controller functions. Seems longer though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a thing if its not important to redirect just make an ajax call and pass the value of the clicked button and from the controller redirect as you want